# Shared_by_me query in my scenario in Django?

Tags: django, model

I have two models like this:

```
class File(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.TextField()
    end_date = models.TextField()
    duration = models.TextField()
    size_overview = models.IntegerField()
    size = models.TextField()
    flag = models.TextField()
    #delete_date = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Share(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    files = models.ForeignKey(File)
    shared_user_id = models.IntegerField()
    shared_date = models.TextField()
```

I get the user id of logged in user as: `log_id = request.user.id`

I want to retrieve files shared by the currently logged in user.

First I queries in Share model:

```
Share.objects.filter(users_id=log_id)
```

`users_id` attribute contains the id of the user that shared the file. Now I know the files_id shared by log_id user. How can I retrieve file information. I want to show `file_name, size and source.`
How can I do that?

Comment: I don't fully understand but if you mean accessing the file attributes you can look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/.

When you have a share instance you could just use: share_instance.files.size

Comment: I mean accessing attributes of my File model.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the inverse relation:

```
File.objects.filter(shares__users__id = log_id)
```

BTW: What about the users field in the File object? How does it relate to the users field in the Share object?

Comment: files field in Share model is related to File. User object is from the inbuild django User model.

Comment: where does shares come from? I am getting this error: Cannot resolve keyword 'shares' into field

Comment: Try to use share instead of shares

Answer (score 0):

If you have your queryset assuming that there are more that one Share instance with the same user:

```
shares = Share.objects.filter(users_id=log_id)
```

You can loop through it and access each of the instances' file:

```
for share in shares:
    print share.files.file_name
    print share.files.type
    print share.files.source
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
File.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(shared_user_id = log_id).values_list('files', flat=True))
```

Comment: 'long' object is not iterable

Comment: Edited the answer. Please be sure you are placing the filter on right fields